# WordPress Post Publishing Failed

Tags: wordpress

Whenever, I try to publish posts, I get this notification "WordPress post publishing failed". How to solve this. I removed few plugins and tried to save it again. But problem is not solved.

Answer (score 0):

If you are experiencing this issue after WordPress version upgrade, you should downgrade the version. This will quick fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

i have Faced same problem but i have change the permalink structure settings than issue is resolved. please you can try to change permalink settings. admin dashboard->settings->permalinks.

```
also read this articals: 
https://getlink.pro/collection?term=How+to+fix+Wordpress+5+Publishing+failed+or+Updating+failed+issue
```